# Reasons to strongly type parameters in PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

When you bind parameters to SQL statement, you can provide parameter type like `PDO::PARAM_STR`. If you don't, type defaults to `PDO::PARAM_STR`. What can be the reasons to specifically set the type of each parameter? PDO::PARAM_STR works with any parameter as I know at least in MySQL. I think even with PDO::PARAM_STR can be used even with BLOB columns.

PDO::PARAM_STR does not introduce any SQL injection because you still have prepared queries.

Answer (score 7):

Using `PARAM_STR` happens to always work in column values because mySQL [implicitly converts values to the correct type where it can](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html), but it will fail for example in this query:

```
$limit = 1;

$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM items LIMIT :limit");
$dbh->bindParam(":limit", $limit, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
     // Will throw "You have an error in your SQL syntax..."
```

one should absolutely use `PARAM_INT` where appropriate - for cases like the one above, and to prepare for database engines other than mySQL that may be more strict in what they expect.

Comment: +1 from me, excellent example. It's not just SQL injection that should be avoided, displaying raw MySQL error messages to user isn't really appealing nor professional so the developer **should** always enforce type safety.

Comment: @N.B. to me it's too boring. I'd prefer concise code over repeating this binding again and again

Comment: What PHP version did you test your code on? I have 5.3.1 on Windows here and no exception is thrown either with PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES or without on parametrized LIMIT clauses as @Col. suggested. And what about other databases? Do they do type conversion as well?

Answer (score 5):

personally I see no reason, as long as you have this attribute set:

```
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );
```

so, it would detect LIMIT case automatically

anyway I'd prefer to define type in a placeholder, not in binding function.

However, my experience with PDO is not that strong. I just tried it out and decided to turn back to plain mysql.