# Is it to specify variable type, PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

I sometimes see:

```
$data = $connection->prepare("sql query...");
$data->bindValue(":my_var_to_replace", $foobar, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$data->execute();
```

but other people simply ommit PDO::PARAM_INT and place the data as an array inside execute (as argument).

Which is preferred? Can it be omitted inside bindValue?

Comment: If you omit it, PDO will use `PDO::PARAM_STR` and treat everything as a string. Sometimes that's fine, other times you want to be more specific. (now thinking of a good specific example of when it matters...)

Comment: In addition to the one linked at the top, [this one has more outside-the-box-thinking examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326720/variable-type-in-pdostatementbindvalue)

Comment: Aha! [And this one as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793340/reasons-to-strongly-type-parameters-in-pdo).  The `LIMIT` use case is one you might regularly encounter.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski ok thanks, those ones are good.